# Mule ESB: DataMapper unable to handle Huge data ( 48Kb-xsd) become non responsible - Version 3.5

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-el, mule-component

i'm using data mapper where i'm trying to convert xml to csv format. I have xsd ( 48kb) when i try to load ( creating mapping) with CSV. Always Datamapper not able to load and soon after it becomes non responding and because of that mule studio itself getting closed. Is that any limitation in dataMapper to load data.

How do i handle this Situation, do we have any alternative way to handle. Kindly suggest. I'm using Mule Version 3.5. Not able to proceed further.

Edit: I have tried to generate xsd from its xml through Datamapper. But it is generated. Plm happens when trying to load xsd directly. Any help on this is very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to simplify the mapping to verify whether there is an issue in the mapping file?

Comment: Problem didnt resolved yet.Client has shared their Xsd ( need to convert xml to csv). Just i'm trying to load in Datamapper. But it is getting hanged and became non responsible while loading itself. @gabe Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Hey i think this is still open.. i faced similar issue but it got resolved by using "Streaming" concept wherein based on the given size, it will read the data and send it to next processor and mapper will continue to read rest of the data

Answer (score 0):

DataMapper has been deprecated some years ago since Mule 3.7. I recommend to try to enable streaming. If that fails then you should consider migrating to a newer release and migrate the transformation to DataWeave.